# Why doesn't WSAIoctl(fd, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, ...) seem to have any effect?

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, keep-alive

Today I'm experimenting with the Windows WSAIoctl(fd, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, ...) call under Windows 7, to see if I can use it to detect more quickly when the Ethernet cable has been pulled on a device that my Windows 7 machine is talking to via the LAN switch.  My call to it looks like this:

```
[...]
struct tcp_keepalive vals; memset(&vals, 0, sizeof(vals));
vals.onoff             = 1;    // non-zero means "enable"
vals.keepalivetime     = 50;   // milliseconds
vals.keepaliveinterval = 100;  // milliseconds
DWORD numBytesReturned = 0;  // not really used AFAICT
int ret = WSAIoctl(fd, SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, &vals, sizeof(vals), NULL, 0, &numBytesReturned, NULL, NULL);
printf("WSAIoctl returned %s\n", (ret==0)?"SUCCESS":"ERROR");
```

My test is to connect my client's TCP socket to the server (via the Ethernet LAN), then unplug the server's Ethernet port, then tell my client to send one byte on the TCP socket, and then I time how long it takes for the client to realize there is a problem and error out the connection.  (My client is using non-blocking I/O via a select() loop which is implemented correctly AFAIK; outside of the added call to WSAIoctl() it's mature code)

What I would expect to see is that with this call, my client would detect the problem and error out within a few seconds; however what I actually observe is that it takes ~35 seconds to detect the problem, whether I call the WSAIoctl() or not, and regardless of what values I pass to it.

So it seems that WSAIoctl() is not having the effect I thought it would, even though it returns 0/success.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or my expectations incorrect somehow?

Comment: The timeout will happen after TCP times out the sends. That interval doesn't have anything to do with the values you've set here. What you're setting is the interval of the probes. And as your client is doing a send after the cable pull, the send timeout will happen anyway, regardless of the keepalive settings. Your testing methodology is flawed.

Comment: @EJP I was under the impression that the TCP packet-resend-timeout threshold in Windows would be calculated as (keepalivetime+(maxprobecount*keepaliveinterval)), similar to what Linux does.  It sounds like you are saying that the TCP packet-resend-timeout threshold in Windows does not depend on those values at all.  Is that correct?